# C++ Adding variables in if functions

Tags: c++

I'm doing rather beginner work with C++ and I am having a difficult time understanding what I am doing wrong with a simple program I am writing. So far, I have got the program written out some what properly, but I am confused on how to place variable place holders in IF Functions. Assuming of course, that is what is supposed to make it work properly.

To start with a little background on how the program is supposed to function. The user enters a 4-digit code and as long as the last digit of the code is a "7" it should display "Origin: Florida". Part two of the IF function would be, if the user enters a 4-digit number and the last digit of the code is a "4" it should display "Origin: California". I finished it with an else statement for any other entries to display "Invalid". The problem I am having is figuring out how to add variable digits for the first 3-digits of the code and when the last digit is entered with a "7" or "4" have a certain "Origin" displayed. I have searched and searched for guides on the interwebs for help, but I've had very little luck. If anyone could help me with this I would be very grateful for the assistance.

Below is the code I've written so with of course fault being in the IF statements:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Digits = 0;

    cout << " ..:::Grocery Program:::.. " << endl;
    cout << " ..::Created By Justin::.. " << endl;
    cout << "\n";   

    cout << " Enter the orange's 4-digit code: ";
    cin >> Digits;

    if ( Digits == 7 )
    {
        cout << " Origin: Florida ";
    }
    else if ( Digits == 0004 )
    {
        cout << " Origin: California ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Origin: Invalid ";
    }

    cout << "\n";   
    cout << "\n";   
    cout << "\n";   
    cout << "\n";   
    cout << "\n";       
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try with `Digits % 10 == 7`

Comment: It won't make a difference here, but `0004` is an octal literal, and equivalent to `04`, which is just 4. Were you to do, say, `0014`, it would have the value 12.

Comment: Is there a way to put placeholders or variables in the If Functions? So someone could enter  3324 or 1274 and it display the "Origin: Florida".

Comment: @TranquilityByDesign: If you have to work on codes that are more complex than simple numbers (say phonenumbers like `+316-1111-2222`), you'd use "Regular Expressions". Those have explicit placeholders. In this simple case, we could write the regular expression `^\d{3}4$` which means start with 3 digits, then a 4. As yu see, for simple examples regular expressions are a bit overkill. In C++ they're provided by the `<regex>` header.

Answer (score 1):

A useful "trick" is to use the modulo (`%`) operator to get a number's digits. Say you want to get the last one...

```
int n = 1234;
int last_digit = n % 10; // last_digit == 4
```

To get the one next to the last, divide the number by 10 (which makes the last digit to go away) and do the same:

```
n /= 10;
int second_to_last = n % 10; // second_to_last == 3
```

Comment: It seems by doing that you can only receive the first number of the integer without bumping into doubles. I am looking in this case to have the last number of the 4-digit code to be the KEY in the equation that provides which answer to display.                            Such as, entering 1234 or 2234 or 5564  "Origin: Florida"             and,     entering 1237 or 2237 or 5567  "Origin: California".       So no matter the first 3 #'s of the 4-digit code I need the last digit to be the determining factor of which message to display. Is there a type of variable I can use with absolute 4th digit

Comment: @TranquilityByDesign: Computers don't store digits (base 10), they store bits (base 2). That's why you need the explicit `% 10`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:
First, you may need to validate if the entered number of digits are 4,
Something like this:
// "number" is unsigned int so we remove the possibility of entering -ve number
    int digits = 0;
    while (number) 
    {
         number /= 10;
         digits++;
    }

If the digits != 4 display invalid, otherwise check the last digit using the Modulo operator  as mentioned by @Faranwath.
Yes, and one more thing you need to save the number as you will need it later on to check the last digit.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I believe everyone is giving me wonderful answers to the problem, yet I have no clue how to implement that into what I am working on. I'll google around a bit for implementation and hopefully figure out what you guys mean  lol     Thank you for the help!